# How to get display the facebook response on the page/obtain the data of facebook user?

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

I am a beginner to create a Facebook tab.
I try to use the Facebook Javascript SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to create it. I know that when the user has authorized his/her information, there is a response stored this information. However, I don't know how to obtain this value in order to display on the webpage. I only know that ajax should be used in this case, but I have nearly no knowledge about ajax. Therefore, I want to know whether there is any sample code to solve this problem. Thank you.

There is a part of code in the index.php. I am using Slim framework and RedBeans.

```
$app->map('/intro', function () use($app) {

    $app_id = "XXXXXXXXX";
    $app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

    $introduction = R::findOne('introduction', 'id = 1');
    $name = $introduction->name;
    $description = $introduction->description;

    $req = $app->request();
    $var = $req->post('args');

    print_r($var);
    $data = array(
        'title' => $name,
        'heading' => $description,
        'app_id' => $app_id,
        'app_secret' => $app_secret,
        'uid' => $var.id
    );

    $app->render('/question/tpl_intro.php', $data);
})->via('GET', 'POST');
```

Answer (score 1):

the facebook api uses an event based system. what this means to you, is that you need to register callback functions that facebook can call when certain events happen on their system.

the first thing you need to do after linking in the fb jssdk is to add the FB.init() call. after this call is done, you can hook into whatever javascript of yours you want to load details for the user.

```
<script type='text/javacript'>
    function AttachHandlers() {
        // getLoginStatus checks if the user is logged in and authorized your app, just
        // logged in and hasn't authorized your app, or isn't logged in.
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected') {
                // if they're logged in and you're authorized, you can actually
                // query facebook for details on the user. 
                FB.api('/me', function(data) {
                    //data will have user details in it.
                    //console.log(data);
                    local args = {name: ''};
                    if (data.email)
                        args.email = data.email;
                    if (data.first_name)
                        args.name = data.first_name;
                    if (data.last_name)
                        args.name += ' ' + data.last_name;
                    // and on and on for as many properties as you need
                    $.post('http://www.yoursite.com/posthandler.php', 
                           args, 
                           function (d, status, xhr) { console.log(d); });
                });
            }
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({appId: 'yourID', status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true, xfbml: true});
        // now the facebook api is loaded properly, you can now start using it.
        AttachHandlers();
    }
</script>
```

Essentially, once the library is loaded - you just pass it some of your own functions that it can call to update you when things happen with that user on facebook (logging in/out, authorizing/unauthorizing your app, etc).

Comment: I want to ask whether this function (AttachHandlers) is same as the function mentioned in Facebook developer page. Actually, I have already follow the step mentioned in Facebook page. However, I don't know how to get the response via javascript.

Comment: Actually, what I need is getting the value of the user and pass them to the templates for rendering the webpage.

Comment: `AttachHandlers()` is an example function I wrote to show you how to hook into their API after it is loaded. You can do this hooking in a variety of ways depending on what you need to do. As for your second question, I have no idea what that means because you didn't mention how you are generating pages, what frameworks you are using, what language you're using, etc.

Comment: I am using Slim framework to write the php page. In this framework, the index.php and the templates are different files, for different url, the page will pass corresponding variable to the corresponding templates for rendering the page. And then, I want to get the id, name, email, birthday of the Facebook user and put them into the database. I think I should use post method to pass these variables to the page, but I don't know how to use the post method in javascript/jquery/ajax to do this. Can you help me?

Comment: Yeah, I added examples that show you how to scrape data from the fb object it passes to you, and how you'd use that to pass data along via jQuery $.post() to your handler that will grab/save the details.

Comment: After that, should the data object be obtained in the http://www.yoursite.com/posthandler.php by using request?

Comment: no, the params will be received in your page in the _POST object.

Comment: As Slim framework is used,  $req = $app->request();
    $var = $req->post('args'); , these two statements are used to grab the args object. Is there wrong? And what should I do?

Comment: hmm, i've no experience with the Slim framework and i'm only familiar with php as I mostly do .NET web development. i can't really help you there, sorry.

Comment: If I put the code you gave in the template, the args object should be received in the page in the _POST object. Is it true?

Comment: yeah, it should. make sure the $.post() call isn't throwing any error for some reason, and if not, the page you're posting to should see the args object come through in the _POST object. unless the Slim framework does something I don't know about.